# Only one javascript IndexedDb connection per browser session allowed?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I find it difficult to believe a javascript connection to indexedDb cannot be established, closed, then re-established within a single javascript instance/browser tab (ie. no browser page refresh or closing current tab). However when I read specs like
https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#close-a-database-connection it sounds as though that is the case. Has anyone had luck closing a indexedDb connection and re-establishing WITHOUT closing the browser tab or hard page refresh? If so how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Opening multiple connections (one after the other is closed etc) is possible within the same "session" (what do you mean by session?).

For example:

```js
function open(name) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const request = indexedDB.open(name);
    request.onsuccess = event => resolve(request.result);
    request.onerror = event => reject(request.error);
  });
}

async function main() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log('Opening database connection', i);
    const connection = await open('mydb');
    console.log('Database connection %s opened to', i, connection.name);

    // do stuff with the connection here

    console.log('Requesting database connection %s to close eventually', i);
    connection.close();
  }
}

main().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Maybe there is a better term for it than session but what I mean is loading a javascript and not reloading or refreshing the browser tab it is running in. The browser does not seem to release the database connection for reconnecting to a db store.

Comment: `IDBDatabase.prototype.close` is a  synchronous call that returns immediately, and then, in the background, the database connection is eventually closed once no more work is being done or pending. It is eventually closed unless you have encountered an error in a browser, which is unlikely.

Comment: The browser seems to keep the connection even on tab refresh. I have no idea where the connection is being stored in the browser (it does not appear to be published to the browser developer console). I'm assuming the browser sets up some sort of session linked to the tab that opened the database. I have reached out to Chrome to have this feature added to indexeddb as it seems rather important to allow opening and closing the database within the same user session and to confirm that in fact this feature does not currently exist.

Comment: Are you working in a service worker context? How are you reaching the conclusion that the browser retains an open connection even on tab refresh?